# Animaciones simultanes en CSS

Tags: css3, animación

Estoy experimentando con las animaciones de CSS, y no encuentro una manera de que dos animaciones transcurran al mismo tiempo. Probé varias maneras, por ejemplo escribir las dos etiquetas HTML en la misma linea, o que los dos elementos tengan la misma animación, y este ultimo funciona, pero necesito que las animaciones sean distintas, esto es lo que intente:

```css
.item-lista {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: item-fall;
}

@keyframes item-fall {
  from {
    margin-top: -800%;
  }

  to {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.link-p {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(240, 129, 56, 1);
}

.link:hover {
  text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px rgba(240, 129, 56, 0.8);
}

#item-3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}

#item-2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
}

#item-1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 170px;
}

#a-logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 12px;
  color: rgba(240, 129, 56, 1);;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 80%;
    width: 280%
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#logo::after {
  content: " Probando animaciones";
  font-size: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

#logo:hover::after {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <div id="logo"><a href="#1" id="a-logo"><strong>FM</strong></a></div>
        <div id="logo-close"></div>
        <ul>
          <li class="item-lista" id="item-1"><a href="#1" class="link-p">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="item-lista" id="item-2"><a href="#2" class="link">About</a></li>
          <li class="item-lista" id="item-3"><a href="#3" class="link">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Necesito que las animaciones slidein e item-fall transcurran al mismo tiempo. Desde ya gracias

Comment: Puedes crear una `clase` o en `id` y darle el valor de `animation-duration: 3s;` y `animation-name: slidein;`, si mal no entendí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las dos animaciones ocurren al mismo tiempo. El problema es que, aunque ambas tienene el mismo tiempo de ejecución de 1 segundo, una tiene que recorrer mucho más espacio que la otra, entonces se van a ver a diferentes velocidades.

Por ejemplo, la animación `slide-in` coloca el elemento fuera de pantalla por la derecha dándole un `margin-left` de 80%, y lo mueve hasta que tiene un `margin-left` de 0. Eso quiere decir que tiene que recorrer el equivalente a un 80% del ancho de pantalla en 1 segundo, y será visible muy pronto (porque apenas está fuera de la zona visible).

Mientras tanto, la animación `item-fall` coloca el elemento fuera de la pantalla por arriba dándole un `margin-top` de -800%, y lo mueve hasta que tiene un `margin-top` de 0. Eso quiere decir que tiene que recorrer el equivalente a un 800% del ancho de pantalla (verticalmente) en un segundo, y será visible mucho más tarde que el elemento de la animación `slide-in` (porque está muy lejos de la zona visible).

Resumiendo: tus dos animaciones se ejecutan correctamente al mismo tiempo (si te fijas terminan a la vez) pero, debido a la diferencia de espacio que tienen que recorrer y cuando entran en la zona visible de la pantalla, parece que una (`slide-in`) se ejecuta antes que la otra (`item-fall`). Aunque ese no sea el caso.

Para que parezca que se ejecutan a la vez, deberías jugar un poco con los valores del tiempo (pero entonces una acabaría antes que la otra, aunque podrías usar retrasos para prevenirlo) o con los valores del posicionamiento (lo cual puede ser algo más sencillo).

Aquí he hecho un cambio en el que ambas se ven al mismo tiempo, la idea ha sido reducir el tamaño de la distancia a recorrer para la animación `item-fall` de -800% a -8%:

```css
.item-lista {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: item-fall;
}

@keyframes item-fall {
  from {
    margin-top: -8%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.link-p {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(240, 129, 56, 1);
}

.link:hover {
  text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px rgba(240, 129, 56, 0.8);
}

#item-3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}

#item-2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
}

#item-1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 170px;
}

#a-logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 12px;
  color: rgba(240, 129, 56, 1);
  ;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 80%;
    width: 280%
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#logo::after {
  content: " Probando animaciones";
  font-size: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

#logo:hover::after {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="logo"><a href="#1" id="a-logo"><strong>FM</strong></a></div>
  <div id="logo-close"></div>
  <ul>
    <li class="item-lista" id="item-1"><a href="#1" class="link-p">Inicio</a></li>
    <li class="item-lista" id="item-2"><a href="#2" class="link">About</a></li>
    <li class="item-lista" id="item-3"><a href="#3" class="link">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: aunque ese valor va a depender un poco de si la pantalla es en modo vertical u horizontal. Quizás sería mejor plantearse usar medidas como `vmin` o `vmax` para asegurarse de que la animación va a empezar fuera de la zona visible.